# How to go through an array and add certain values?

Tags: java

I'll try to explain it better.

So k = 2.
In[]profits = new {1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 10}

For the first part it should be:

1,2,3

Then look for the least value in {1,2,3} which is 1. Then add that to the next value which is 1. So it would be 1+1. The outcome would be {2,3,2}. Again look for the least value which is 2 and add it to the next value 6. So it would be 2+6. The outcome would be {3, 2, 8}. Finally, for the least value in {3,2,8} and add it to the next value 10. So it would be and 10+2. The outcome is {2, 8, 10}. Then look for the least value in that which is 2.

If you guys could at least guide me on how to do this?

This is the tester:

```
import java.util.Arrays ;

 /**
 Presents some problems to the BillBoard class.
 */

public class BillboardTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] profits = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 10} ;

        int k = 2 ;

        System.out.println("Profits: " + Arrays.toString(profits) + "   k = " + k)  ;

        Billboard bb = new Billboard(profits, k) ;
        System.out.println("Maximum Profit = " + bb.maximumProfit()) ;
        System.out.println(bb) ;

        k = 3 ;
        profits = new int[]{7, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 8, 9, 2, 5} ;
        System.out.println("Profits: " + Arrays.toString(profits) + "   k = " + k)  ;
        bb = new Billboard(profits, k) ;
        System.out.println("Maximum Profit = " + bb.maximumProfit()) ;
        System.out.println(bb) ;
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far for the class:

```
public class Billboard {
    private int maximumprofit; // The max profit 
    private int finalcost; // The final cost of removing the billboards

    public Billboard(int[]profits, int k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < profits.length; i++) {
            maximumprofit+= profits[i];
        }
    }

    public int maximumProfit() {
        return maximumprofit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your sample example is confusing. Why are you adding `6 + 2` for `3, 2`?

Comment: Yeah, your example is REALLY confusing. Also it seems like sometimes you're checking 3 numbers and sometimes only 2...?

Comment: realy it is going top of my head.

Comment: This is confusing. Can you explain what goes in a function, and what should come out? Maybe the even business use case.

Comment: Ok, I see your updated example. What exactly does `k` mean?

Comment: k i believe means the amount of variables you look at in this case if k = 2. You look at {1, 2, 3}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have `k+1` possible totals, and you add each new element of profits to the LOWEST current total profit no matter what it is. So in your example, it's really

- `1, 2, 3`
- `1+1=2, 2, 3`
- `2+6=8, 2, 3`
- `8, 2+10=12, 3`

For a final array of

- `8, 12, 3` -> Lowest value is actually `3`

If this is what you meant (you never said what `k` is), this code will do the job. I left a line of debugging code in there to help you check for correctness.

```
public class Billboard
{
    private int[] profits;
    private int k;
    public Billboard(int[]profits, int k)
    {
        this.profits = profits;
        this.k = k+1; // I changed this to k+1 because you have 3 totals with k = 2
    }
    public int maximumProfit() {
        int[] bottom = new int[k];

        for(int i = 0; i < profits.length; i++) {
            int minIndex = 0;
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                if (bottom[j] < min) {
                    minIndex = j;
                    min = bottom[j];
                }
            }
            bottom[minIndex] += profits[i];
        }

        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            System.out.println("TestDump: #"+i+" is: " + bottom[i]);
            if (bottom[i] < min) {
                min = bottom[i];
            }
        }

        return min;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Billboard bb = new Billboard(new int[]{1,2,3,1,6,10}, 2);
        System.out.println("Maximum profit = " + bb.maximumProfit());
    }
}
```

This code outputs

```
TestDump: #0 is: 8
TestDump: #1 is: 12
TestDump: #2 is: 3
Maximum profit = 3
```

To change what the `Billboard` class outputs when you put it in `System.out.println(bb)`, you have to override the `toString` method of the `Billboard` class, i.e.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return (new StringBuider(totalProfit - maxProfit)).toString();
}
```

Assuming you set the fields in the class to have the correct values earlier.

Comment: I know it's cofusing but let me try to explain it better.

Comment: @RogerioRibeiro: I updated my post. My code works exactly as you need it to, except I'm not sure why you have 3 running totals when `k=2`, and I'm not sure why when you have `{2,3,8}`, you do `2+10` and result with `{2,8,10}`, it should be `{2+10,3,8}` See the above trace.

Comment: Yea, i know i don't really understand the concept with the k but that is how it was explained to me. It seems as tho if k = 2 then we look at the 3 values. About the {2, 8, 10} i meant {2, 8, 12}. It's not {2,3,8} it is {3, 2, 8} Then you look at the least which is 2 and add that onto 10, getting the final value of {2, 8, 12}.

Comment: I should also add maximum profit should be the total of the array {1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 10} = 54. Then we subtracted it by what we call the final cost which would be 2 in this case if you look at {2, 8, 12} because we need the least value.

Comment: Sorry.... made a typo. {1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 10} does not equal 54 it equals 23.

Comment: I still have no idea what `k` means.

Comment: I got it to work it printed out the values i need. I just need to add  for (int i = 0; i < profits.length; i++) {
      maximumprofit+= profits[i];
  } and this.k = k*2 to the code and it worked perfectly. Thank You for you help.

Comment: @RogerioRibeiro: If my solution worked don't forget to hit the green checkmark

Comment: Hey, i might have arised another problem. The system.out.println(bb). That should be printing what arrays i need removed my max profit and my remaining profit. Here is the output that i should get: Billboards removed (profit): 3(1) 0(1)  => profit loss of 2
 total value of billboards = 23
 remaining maximum profit = 21

Comment: You can override `Billboard.toString()` to print the correct number.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you mean? In the tester or in the class?